# вывод текста на экран в vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Начал пытаться изучать питон и возникла проблема.
Скачал `vscode`, пишу код любой (например `print ("hello world")`) жму отладку через питон и ничего не происходит, просто открывается новая вкладка "параметры пользователя", в чем проблема?

Comment: Такую же ошибку получил после установки и запуска vs code первый раз. Сначала надо расширение для питона поставить и настроить vs code

Comment: Ещё... При создании файла сохранил его уже как _file.py_ при отладке запросило ещё _pylink_. Установил и после этого при запуске программы  появился список в котором выбрал _Python: Terminal (integrated)_ и программа запустилась. Попробую ещё дома установить)

Comment: Здесь описана настройка VS Code для работы с Python [Getting Started with Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)